# How to set maximum concurrent threads using Task

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am writing a stress testing utility. In this utility I want that I continuously put load of 10 threads (out of 10,000). Here is my code

```
            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();

        int itemProcessed = 0;

        do
        {
            List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
            for (int i = 0; i < _parallelThreadCount; i++)
            {
                taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _taskDelegate()));
                itemProcessed++;
            }
            Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
        } while (itemProcessed < _batchSize);

        watch.Stop();
```

Now the problem is that I have use Task.WaitAll, due to which Initially load is 10 threads, then 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0. And then again I add 10 More threads.

Can someone give me idea that how to achieve this.

Comment: Is there any specific reason, why you can't use Parallel class instead of List<Task>?

Comment: I just want to make sure that only 10 threads are running at a time

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you could restructure your code a bit (read: replace your `do while` loop), you can make use of the [`Parallel` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.aspx). Here's a quick example:

```
List<int> data = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
Parallel.ForEach(data, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, d =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(d);
});
```

The bit you're likely most interested in is the [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx) property of `ParallelOptions` - it specifies how many threads can be running at the same time.

EDIT:

As you don't have a list of tasks but rather just want to repeat the same operation a number of times, then you can use `Parallel.For`. Here's what the code might look like:

```
int repeatCount = 100;
int itemProcessed = 0;
Parallel.For(0, repeatCount, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, i =>
{
    _taskDelegate();
    System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref itemProcessed);
});
```

Note that if the only reason you used `itemProcessed` was to check how long your loop is to work, you can safely remove the two lines from the code above.

Answer (score 18):

Shaamaan's answer is good and probably the one that you want to go with for your particular scenario. I'm just presenting a couple other possible options that you could use, and that may be more applicable for other situations.

[My blog post](http://blog.danskingdom.com/limit-the-number-of-c-tasks-that-run-in-parallel/) shows how to do this both with Tasks and with Actions, and provides a sample project you can download and run to see both in action.

## With Actions

If using Actions, you can use the built-in .Net Parallel.Invoke function. Here we limit it to running at most 10 threads in parallel.

```
var listOfActions = new List<Action>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    // Note that we create the Action here, but do not start it.
    listOfActions.Add(() => DoSomething());
}

var options = new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10};
Parallel.Invoke(options, listOfActions.ToArray());
```

## With Tasks

With Tasks there is no built-in function. However, you can use the one that I provide on my blog.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the given tasks and waits for them to complete. This will run, at most, the specified number of tasks in parallel.
    /// <para>NOTE: If one of the given tasks has already been started, an exception will be thrown.</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tasksToRun">The tasks to run.</param>
    /// <param name="maxTasksToRunInParallel">The maximum number of tasks to run in parallel.</param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken">The cancellation token.</param>
    public static void StartAndWaitAllThrottled(IEnumerable<Task> tasksToRun, int maxTasksToRunInParallel, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        StartAndWaitAllThrottled(tasksToRun, maxTasksToRunInParallel, -1, cancellationToken);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the given tasks and waits for them to complete. This will run, at most, the specified number of tasks in parallel.
    /// <para>NOTE: If one of the given tasks has already been started, an exception will be thrown.</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tasksToRun">The tasks to run.</param>
    /// <param name="maxTasksToRunInParallel">The maximum number of tasks to run in parallel.</param>
    /// <param name="timeoutInMilliseconds">The maximum milliseconds we should allow the max tasks to run in parallel before allowing another task to start. Specify -1 to wait indefinitely.</param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken">The cancellation token.</param>
    public static void StartAndWaitAllThrottled(IEnumerable<Task> tasksToRun, int maxTasksToRunInParallel, int timeoutInMilliseconds, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        // Convert to a list of tasks so that we don&#39;t enumerate over it multiple times needlessly.
        var tasks = tasksToRun.ToList();

        using (var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(maxTasksToRunInParallel))
        {
            var postTaskTasks = new List<Task>();

            // Have each task notify the throttler when it completes so that it decrements the number of tasks currently running.
            tasks.ForEach(t => postTaskTasks.Add(t.ContinueWith(tsk => throttler.Release())));

            // Start running each task.
            foreach (var task in tasks)
            {
                // Increment the number of tasks currently running and wait if too many are running.
                throttler.Wait(timeoutInMilliseconds, cancellationToken);

                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                task.Start();
            }

            // Wait for all of the provided tasks to complete.
            // We wait on the list of "post" tasks instead of the original tasks, otherwise there is a potential race condition where the throttler&#39;s using block is exited before some Tasks have had their "post" action completed, which references the throttler, resulting in an exception due to accessing a disposed object.
            Task.WaitAll(postTaskTasks.ToArray(), cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

And then creating your list of Tasks and calling the function to have them run, with say a maximum of 10 simultaneous at a time, you could do this:

```
var listOfTasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    var count = i;
    // Note that we create the Task here, but do not start it.
    listOfTasks.Add(new Task(() => Something()));
}
Tasks.StartAndWaitAllThrottled(listOfTasks, 10);
```

Comment: Great answer, but how would you change this answer so that `listOfTasks` is a list of Task<TResult> and the method is `async Task<TResult> Something()` ? I had trouble creating the task list with "cold" async methods.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is loosely based on @deadlydog answer, but is for those that have an async/await function that you want to run. The order of execution is not guaranteed (this is not a queue), but all the tasks should run.

```cs
var items = GetRandomNumbers(10, 3000, 10000).ToArray();
var tasks = new List<Task>();
using var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(3);

for (var i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{
    var nbr = i;
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await throttler.WaitAsync(-1, CancellationToken.None);
        try
        {
            // Your code here
            var item = items[nbr];
            Console.WriteLine($"Starting task {nbr}. Delay {item}ms.");
            await Task.Delay(item);
            Console.WriteLine($"Completed task {nbr}. Delay {item}ms.");
        }
        finally
        {
            throttler.Release();
        }
    }));
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());


static IEnumerable<int> GetRandomNumbers(int count, int min = 0, int max = int.MaxValue)
{
    var rand = new Random();
    var values = new List<int>();

    for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        values.Add(rand.Next(min, max));

    return values;
}
```